# Pressure switch and wattage temperature control of water heater

Tags: heater

I need this last data to help decide what to do with it. Note for Multipoint heaters located not inside shower area, one doesnt usually turn if off, so this safety is bypassed. Anyway this photo shows another brand with thermostat control from low to high like in a radio button or volume

[image]

It can even get warm with very little water. Does electronic control of temperature give another layer of safety? Like it cant suddenly go to maximum? Because i may buy another just like in the picture if electronic control of temperature add another safety layer and give away the old heater or take it apart as an electronic collection.

Previous post

The instant tankless water heater has 3 switches: low, medium and high. The spec mentions when at low, 2.5kw is used, medium at 3.5kw and high at 6kw. Does it use full wattage is used or can it adjust at say low temp switch to say just 1kw. Here is the power diagram.

[image]

In the original i was contemplating about replacing the pressure switch with a flow switch so it can turn on at lower water pressure:

Any illustration what is inside the pressure switch water pusher (the white round thing encircled in green label) of this instant tankless multipoint water heater?  When there is certain pressure, it pushes the switch on the left of the round white part

Also why don't they just use a flow switch instead of a pressure switch?

[image]

Comment: looks like some sort of diaphragm

Comment: not really an electronics question ... ask at a mechanics related website

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not an EE question. Take it apart and have a look.

Comment: I plan to replace it with a flow switch hence electronic question. What flow switch can be used?

Answer (score 3):

It will contain a diaphragm and a spring applying opposing pressure to a load-spreading plate or washer on the dry side of the diaphragm (to prevent rupture).

> Also why don't they just use a flow switch instead of a pressure switch?

"Just"? A flow switch is more complex, more expensive and more likely to jam due to foreign material ingress.

> I plan to replace it with a flow switch hence electronic question.

Talk to your home insurance provider first.

---

[image]

---

> The thermostat seems connected to the low medium high switch. Shoudn't it be connected to some sort of relays?

Relays would be required if the switch and thermostat contacts were not capable of switching the current. Cost can be saved by avoiding them.

> Haven't you come across heaters where high setting means full 6.5 kW heat used, perhaps in old style heater?

I'm not sure what your question is.

The sensible thing to do would be to use two heaters and have the two switches cam operated as follows:

```
2.5 kW | 3.5 kW | Result
-------+--------+--------
 Off   |  Off   | 0.0 kW
 On    |  Off   | 2.5 kW
 Off   |  On    | 3.5 kW
 On    |  On    | 6.0 kW
```

> If the pressure switch or flow switch malfunctions will the heater still give say 6 kW full power?

There are two other levels of protection. The rotary switches should normally be off and the thermostat contacts would open when the temperature rises.

> If yes, this can cause too high temperature and melt the case.

Melting the case is not the problem. Generating steam and the risk of explosion is. Water expands to 1760 times its volume when converted to steam.

> If not and the thermostat purpose is to control heater power what kind of circuit must it be?

It's a mechanical switch. If temperature goes above the rated temperature then the contacts open. If the temperature goes below the rated temperature then the contacts close.

> The heater unit has only few components, which should the one that regulate heater power, usually?

Thermostat. 100% on or 0% on.

> Or how does the thermostat or switch regulate current? You have seen this done?

On - off control. Yes, I have seen it done on water heaters, electric ovens, clothes irons, washing machines, hair driers, waffle makers, central heating boilers and pumps, dishwashers, ... and they're just things around the house.

Comment: There is no thermal cut off fuse or switch in the heater. You mean a diaphragm based pressure switch like it is safer than a flow switch? Cant a diaphragm based pressure switch jam?

Comment: There should be a thermostat in the water heater unit. Usually a second one is a good idea. There's little likelihood of jamming material building up on the diaphragm.

Comment: The photo angle makes it difficult to tell but my guess would be the silver part nearest the camera in the top middle. If it has two wires on it then that's it. It will be a normally-closed contact type opening when the preset temperature is reached.

Comment: The photo completely missed the top of the heater cylinder where all the action is. The second link to to an ad page and not a datasheet so neither is much use. It's not that "temperature is fixed at 2.5 kW, ..." - it's the **power** level is fixed at each of those settings. You'd need to ask Panasonic about the design decisions. I'd only be guessing.

Comment: See the update. You should post the images in your question, not in links buried in the comments to an answer. Make it easy for your readers!

Comment: Photo of above last question https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img922/2812/29jq7t.jpg

Comment: See the update. Again, your photos should be in the question and you should not be asking us to follow external links.

Comment: See the update again.

Comment: I need this last data to help decide what to do with it. Note for Multipoint heaters located not inside shower area, one doesnt usually turn if off, so this safety is bypassed. Anyway this photo shows another brand with thermostat control from low to high like in volume. https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img923/4761/eaxUka.jpg    It can even get warm with very little water. Does electronic control of temperature give another layer of safety? Like it cant suddenly go to maximum? Because i may buy another just like in the picture if electronic control of temperature add another safety layer.

Comment: I have given you a lot of time already. I'm not going to ask a third time that you post your images in the question. If you can't be bothered then why should I?

Answer (score 1):

The wiring diagram indicates that the thing has a flow switch with two poles, one in series with each heater element.  I assume this switch will open, turning off both heaters, if there is insufficient flow.

The wiring diagram also shows a thermal switch in series with each heater - one is marked "thermostat" in the photo in @transistor's answer - I think I can see the second one mostly hidden by the orange wire.  I suspect that these are thermal switches, intended to shut off the power if the tank overheats, rather than thermostats intended to control the temperature in normal operation - but that's only a guess...

Comment: I think you are right. It's too simple to have temperature control in normal operation. So it just shuts down power if tank overheats. Does this design require more water or pressure?  The heater needs a lot of water/pressure to turn on. So if I change it to a flow switch where any simple flow of water can turn it on, what would be the disadvantage for such heater design where adds 2.5kw + 3.5kw to get 6kw with low medium high switch and shuts down heating element when certain temperature reached?

Comment: The wiring diagram you show says the unit has a flow switch, not a presure switch.  I assume the flow switch will turn off the heaters if the flow is too low to keep the water temperature at a safe level.

Comment: Look at the illustration here https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img924/2055/HMJlHw.jpg  When enough water pressure is reached, it will push on the miniswitch which turns on the heater. Even with little water flow, I can manually turn on the heater by pressing the mini switch (of course with full gloves). I guess they just write "flow switch" for pressure swtich to sound nice unless there are flow switches that can be triggered by pressure? Then how does it differ to a pressure switch?

Comment: A simple flow switch could be a paddle in the water path - flowing water pushes on the paddle, and the paddle will at some point flip the switch.  How far the paddle is pushed over will depend on the flow rate.

Comment: Btw where is the heating element? Is it the copper container itself or is there separate heating element inside each container? How do they look like?

Comment: The heating elements are in the copper container marked "DH-6AM1P  AC-230V 6.0kW" - see all the wires and thermal switches on the top, and the pipes connected to it?

Comment: So the copper container itself is the heater and its empty inside it?

Comment: The heating elements are inside the copper container, and the water will flow into the container, around the elements, and out to wherever you want the hot water.

Comment: If the flow switch and thermostat fail and heating elements run at full 6kw without using any water or heater usage. Then the water will turn to vapor inside, but since the container is tiny, the steam explosion wont be much so i guess it would just burn the entire unit? Im googling about actual tankless water heater explosion but cant find any.